# How to Convert long strings to big numbers

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, numbers, converters

Lets say we want to `Convert/Parse` following string

```
string mystring = "221021290110000123452229211210282900128222900"
```

to an number

Of what type would this number be?

i tested `Double.TryParse(mystring,out myBigNumber)` but i got an `E+` number which i can't use for my mathematical operations because the modulo operation will result in a wrong number

Comment: If your calculation takes double, E+ is not going to give any issue. E+ is a presentation when you print or view.

Comment: but i get the wrong result if i check myBigNumber % 97

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var bigNumber = BigInteger.Parse(mystring);
```

See [`BigInteger.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231.aspx).

As far as I know `BigInteger` is limited by the amount of memory you have available.

Comment: it is available in .NET 4.0 also

Comment: It is also in .NET 4. Click the `Other Versions` on the MSDN page.

Comment: @WiiMaxx that type exists since .NET 4. Click on "other versions" right next to where it says .NET 4.5.

Comment: ahh i just missed the referenz `using System.Numerics;` :o)

Answer (score 2):

[BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) is what you are looking for